# C#, Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c#

In TextBox collection i load the data from Database Table, Its containing data like this "01-carrot" I'm set AutoCompleMode for textbox. But if i enter '01' its showing the related collection but but if i enter 'c' in starting it's not showing any collection Please Suggest me

I tried Code Like This, And Loaded this`enter code here` in Load_page event.

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection;
private void clubitem_no()
{
    try
    {
       // string a = txtitem.Text + "%";
       // DataTable allnames = new DataTable();
       // MySqlCommand cmdauto = new MySqlCommand("SELECT CONCAT(product_id,'-',product_name)AS product_name FROM product_details WHERE product_id LIKE  '"+ a + "' OR product_name LIKE '" + a + "'", conn);
        MySqlCommand cmdauto = new MySqlCommand("SELECT CONCAT(product_id,'-',product_name)AS product_name FROM product_details ", conn); 
      conn.Open();
        MySqlDataReader newdr = cmdauto.ExecuteReader();
         MyCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        while (newdr.Read())
        {
            string b = newdr.GetString(0);
            MyCollection.Add(newdr.GetString(0));

        }
      // txtitem.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyCollection;
       txtitem.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
       txtitem.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
      // AutoCompleteStringCollection DataCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
       txtitem.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyCollection;
        newdr.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Standard auto-completion only searches from the beginning of the text. If you want a search was made in the middle of the text, you have to write the logic autocomplete yourself or use third-party components.

Answer (score 0):

You should use % after like. 
Example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(product_id,'-',product_name)AS product_name FROM product_details WHERE product_id LIKE  '%"+ a + "%' OR product_name LIKE '%" + a + "%'"
```

[Check here for more details](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

Comment: I tried like this also But it's loading all data to collection but when we are searching its taking begging alphabets only.

Comment: if you want to find specific feature, you should write more character. For example: for carot -> %car% it will find all data which has car.

Comment: I would advice against using string concatenation when building sql.  Use parameters instead. 
var sql = "SELECT CONCAT(product_id,'-',product_name)AS product_name FROM product_details WHERE product_id LIKE @search OR product_name LIKE @search";
var search = string.format("%{0}%",a);
cmdauto.parameters.add(new MySqlParameter("search", search));